# create an interface and its generic version

Tags: c#, inheritance, c#-4.0, interface

I want to create an interface and support its generic version and I'm not going to create two separate interface.

```
public interface IVMBase
{
    string ParentPropertyName { get; }

    string ParentForeignKeyPropertyName { get; }

    string ChildsPropertyName { get; }

    bool EnableChangeParent { get; set; }

    RelayCommand<ChangeHierarchyParentArgs<Entity>> ChangeEntityParent { get; set; }
}

public interface IVMBase<T> : IVMBase where T : Entity
{
    new RelayCommand<ChangeHierarchyParentArgs<T>> ChangeEntityParent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class VM<T> :  IVMBase<T> where T : Entity
{
    public RelayCommand<ChangeHierarchyParentArgs<T>> ChangeEntityParent { get; set; }
}
```

Compiler force me to implement two property for none-generic version of interface and its generic version and I dont want it.

Tanks a lot

Comment: *You have to* - but the implementation can be `abstract` or `virtual` with `throw new NotSupportedExeption()`.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are a contract enforced by the runtime and the compiler - you can't make an exception just for yourself.

The behavior of your two `ChangeEntityParent` properties will be different in the generic and non-generic versions, but you can implement it using explicit interface implementation:

```
class Implementation<T> : IVMBase<T>
    where T : Entit
{
    // "explicit implementation" of the IVMBase property:
    RelayCommand<ChangeHierarchyParentArgs<Entity>> IVMBase.ChangeEntityParent
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    // normal implementation of the IVMBase<T> property:
    public RelayCommand<ChangeHierarchyParentArgs<T>> ChangeEntityParent
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

Using explicit-interface implementation allows types to have multiple members with the same name.

Comment: in generic implementation, I dont want to implement none-generic properties. I want to  have only one ChangeEntityParent property. microsoft do it on IEnumerable interface and IEnumerable<T> interface. but I Cant

Comment: @EhsanVali That's false.  Any implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` must implement the non-generic versions of the members.